# Angular, Dexie, invalid date

Tags: angular, typescript, dexie

I have a Angular V13.0.2 app that I am expanding. I just recently added Dexie (indexedDB). Now when I try to add a date to my database I only get a "Invalid Date" statement out of it.

```js
// Export clients
export interface Clients {
    id?: number;
    addressId: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    created: Date;
}
// Create a client
const clientId = await db.clients.add({
   addressId: addressId,
   firstName: 'John',
   lastName: 'Doe',
   created: new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')
});

The visualization is nothing more then a ngFor over the clients. Am I missing something?
```

Comment: just for testing, try only with: created: new Date()

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero that also gives the invalid date statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not very clear. But Dexie.js uses the UNIX epoch time format. For anyone with the same issue, use:

```js
new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')
```

I hope someone somewhere might find this useful.